# Governor limit on trigger clarification

Tags: apex, trigger, governorlimits, bestpractice

If I have a below loop:

```
List<id> var2=new List<id>();
for(Sobject1 s:trigger.new){

var2.add(s.Sobject2);
for(Sobject2 var: [select Sobject2 from Sobject where Id IN:var2){
//do something
}

}
```

The context here does'nt matter. Does the inner for loop may hit the governors limit?

How different the governot limit is for below code, both uses :

```
Map<id,xyz> Amap;
for(sobject var:[select field from Sobject where Id In:Amap.keyset()]){
// do something
}

For(Sobject s:trigger.new){
// do somethign where there is no SOQL involved.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first scenario ,you have still a query inside the FOR loop if you look carefully .

If your loop runs for 200 records ,your query will execute for 200 times but limit inside a context is 100 SOQL ,So you hit the limit .

While Second Scenario is inner SOQL ,The way inline SOQL works is very different than query inside FOR loop

Inside Inline SOQL you don't worry about heap at all .If you instead collect in a list you will see a heap issue if data returned is large . There is an excellent [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm) on this topic that you may want to refer.

Comment: SOQL limit is 100 per transaction. 150 is for DML.

Comment: @VigneshwaranG I have never hitted this limit from past two years so i forgot whats the actual number .Thanks for correction :)

Comment: @MohithShrivastava : does it mean we should never add a query inside a for loop? and always collect the records outside of the for loop?

Comment: @Rdvsm Yes thats correct .Never Never put query inside a for statement .You can use inline SOQL

Comment: Thanks , one more questions - if I write an inline Soql , is it considered as 1 Soql query or multiple Soql ?

Comment: Inline SOQL is only one and inline SOQL are right way to control heap and make apex efficient